# Possible to read files with wildcard in the path name?

Tags: sql

For example,  `/path/to/*/file` can you use SQL to read a file using a wildcard to fill in the absolute path? This is for a situation where I there is one component in the path which changes unpredictably.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, do you want to know if it is possible to query a table with columns where the file paths contains special characters?

Comment: No, is it possible to read a file using SQL query when a foldername in the path is not known but the other folders in the path are.

Comment: I mean if you don't know what the folder between /to/ and /file is called, can you still read /file with SQL query which takes an absolute path paramater

Comment: In what way are you "reading" the file from SQL? Bulk insert? Attaching a database? Restoring a backup? Something else? Also, any possibility that there are multiple directories under `/to` that contain a file called `file`? What would you want to do then?

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever - I am exploring the options, probably bulk insert. As for your question, the files are uniquely named. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no. But if you can look up the valid options by querying the file structure you could then loop around the results. However I would suggest that any system that employed this approach would be wide open to hackers.